# Finding the right algorithm for undirected graph

Tags: graph-algorithm

We are given an undirected graph. There is a `source` and a `sink` and they are not connected directly in all possible cases. I want to find the minimum number of vertices to be removed(**not the source or sink**) that disconnects the `source` and the `sink`.

Is there any specific algorithm for this problem. Links would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**Maximum Flow Minimum Cut Theorem**
It use the minimum cost to separate the graph to two parts, the source node in the first part, and sink in the second.
To set all the weight equal to 1 of all the edges. You can learn this theorem in the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem)